# Integral of Brownian motion in a 2-d box

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $A=(a,b)\times (c,d) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $0 \in A$ and $(B_t)$ be standard two dimensional Brownian motion. Additionally, let $\tau_A := \inf \{t\geq 0: B_t \notin A\}$ and let $g:A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth bounded function which can be written as $g(x,y)=u(x)v(y)$.

I am investigating the random variable
$$\int_0^{\tau_A} g(B_s) ds$$
in particular I am interested in the expectation
$$E[\int_0^{\tau_A} g(B_s) ds].$$
I know that there is a connection to the Dirichlet problem but I am interested in calculating or estimating (in both directions) this expression in a stochastical way. E.g., a bound, which contains the $L^1$ norm of $g$ would be very interesting.
Since the domain $A$ is an "easy" one and $B_t$ consists of two one dimensional independent Brownian motions $B_t=(B_t^1, B_t^2)$, I have tried to reduce the problem into one dimension in the following way:

\begin{align*} 
E[\int_0^{\tau_A} g(B_s) ds] &= E^1 E^2 [\int_0^{\tau_{(a,b)}^1 \wedge  \tau_{(c,d)}^2} g(B_s^1,B_s^2) ds] \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}E^1 \big[ 1_{[0, \tau^1_{(a,b)})}(s)  u(B^1_s) \big] E^2 \big[1_{[0, \tau^2_{(c,d)})}(s) v(B^2_s)\big] d s
\end{align*}

The superscripts $\{1,2\}$ refer to the distributions of the respective Brownian motion.
Now I have no further ideas on how to proceed and am not familiar with tools that could help me here.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you written $U$ and $A$ to mean the same set?
I'll be interested to see what comes of this question, but personally I would embrace the PDE formulation.

Comment: @Ali Yes of course. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I don't know how to be properly stochastic about things
and this might not be too helpful.
Let me rewrite your last equation in a form more familiar to me.
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbb{E}\left[g\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}
  \left(\int_{a}^{b}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\right)
  \left(\int_{c}^{d}\psi_{s}(y)v(y)dy\right)ds.
\end{equation*}
It's not necessary but for simplicity I'll assume
$\left(a,b\right)=\left(c,d\right)=\left(-\pi/2,\pi/2\right)$.
Given initial conditions $\phi_{0}(x)=\delta(x)$ and
$\psi_{0}(y)=\delta(y)$, we solve with
\begin{equation*}
  \phi_{s}(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
  e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}
  \cos\left(\left(2n+1\right)x\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  \psi_{s}(y)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
  e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}
  \cos\left(\left(2n+1\right)y\right).
\end{equation*}
Then with $1\leq p\leq\infty$,
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\leq
  k_{p}
    \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)
\left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{p}}
\end{equation*}
where, for example, $k_{1}=2/\pi$, $k_{2}=\sqrt{2/\pi}$ and $k_{\infty}=4/\pi$.

---

**Edit2**: As @Diger has pointed out in the comments, the better way to proceed
(for $p=\infty$ and $p=2$ respectively) is by
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)\,dx&=&
  \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
  \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\cos\left((2n+1)x\right)
  \right)dx\\
  &=&\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}
    \left(\frac{2(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
implying
\begin{equation*}
  \lVert \phi_{s} \rVert_{L^{1}}
  =\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}}
  {2n+1},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
  \phi_{s}(x)^{2}\,dx
  &=&\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
  \Bigg(\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)^{2}s-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\\
  &&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
  \cos\left((2m+1)x\right)\cos\left((2n+1)x\right)\Bigg)dx\\
  &=&\frac{4}{\pi^{2}}
  \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)^{2}s-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}
  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{m,n}\right)\\
  &=&\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(2n+1)^{2}s}
\end{eqnarray*}
implying
\begin{equation*}
  \left\lVert \phi_{s}\right\rVert_{L^{2}}=
  \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{equation*}
I am embarrassed by the mess I have made of this answer so I'll try and put the
bounty back on the question.

---

\begin{multline*}
  \int_{h}^{\infty}
  \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\right)
  \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\psi_{s}(y)v(y)dy\right) ds\\
  \leq
  k_{p}k_{q}
    \left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{p}}
    \left\lVert v\right\rVert_{L^{q}}
    \int_{h}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)^{2}ds.
\end{multline*}
My guess is that the integral converges for $h>0$.
But is it the sort of thing you are after?
For the integral up to $h$ we might have to rely on the fact
  that $\left\lVert \phi_{s}\right\rVert_{L^{1}}\leq 1$ and therefore be more
  constrained in the choice of norm.
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\leq
\left\lVert \phi_{s}\right\rVert_{L^{1}}
  \left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}
  \leq \left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{multline*}
    \int_{0}^{h}
  \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\right)
  \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\psi_{s}(y)v(y)dy\right) ds\\
  \leq h \left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}
  \left\lVert v\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}= h
  \left\lVert g\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{multline*}
I was surprised that you wanted estimates in terms of
$\left\lVert g\right\rVert_{L^{1}}$
because to me the $L^{\infty}$ norm seems more natural. We are basically integrating against distributions.

---

**Edit1**:
I have changed $\epsilon$ to $h$ in the above.
It was misleading notation because I did not intend $\epsilon\to 0$.
In fact according to Mathematica its optimal value in this setup is
about $h=0.636$.
Let's assume henceforth that we are only interested in $p=q=\infty$.
By the above,
\begin{multline*}
  \mathbb{E}[g]\leq
  h\left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}\left\lVert v\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}
  +k_{\infty}k_{\infty}\lVert u\rVert_{L^{\infty}}\lVert v\rVert_{L^{\infty}}
  \int_{h}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)^{2}ds\\
  =\left(
  h+\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^{2}
  \int_{h}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)^{2}ds
  \right)\left\lVert g\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{multline*}
Mathematica is happy to evaluate that prefactor (with $h$ as above), giving
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbb{E}[g]\leq 1.522 \left\lVert g\right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{equation*}

Is this likely to be a good estimate?
Well let's perform the same procedure in the one-dimensional case
for comparative purposes.
\begin{multline*}
  \mathbb{E}[u]=
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(
  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\right)ds\\
  \leq \left(h+ \frac{4}{\pi}
  \int_{h}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)ds
  \right)\lVert u \rVert_{L^{\infty}}=
   2.505 \left\lVert u \right\rVert_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{multline*}
In the one-dimensional case, we know the expected survival time is
$\pi^{2}/4$ (see @Diger's comment below). Consider $u(x)=1$.
Then $\mathbb{E}[u]=\pi^{2}/4=2.467$, only slightly less than $2.505$.
So these estimates aren't looking terrible!

BUT $\pi^{2}/4$ is clearly the better estimate, if only slightly.
Why is that? In the above I calculated
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left\lvert \cos \left((2n+1) x\right)\right\rvert dx=2.
\end{equation*}
However in the comments @Diger calculated
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos \left((2n+1) x\right) dx=
2(-1)^{n}/(2n+1).
\end{equation*}
In fact I think @Diger's approach is valid, and of course it gives
a slightly better estimates.
Its validity stems from the nonnegativity of the probability
distribution throughout its domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go through your answer in detail and share my thoughts afterwards. But as I am not very familiar with those PDE things, could you briefly explain how one obtains the expressions for $\phi_s(x)$ and $\psi_s(y)$ at the beginning?

Comment: Ha I thought I was concealing my PDE inclinations by taking my lead from your working—and by not mentioning any PDEs! But you are right they were on my mind. I just took the expressions for $\phi$ and $\psi$ (with simplifications) from the first article Google provides for "heat equation on a finite interval". But one great advantage of PDEs that we have missed is that for this problem we could lose the time component entirely, dealing only with the corresponding Poisson's equation $\Delta f + g=0$.

Comment: Just curious: Are you sure the prefactor of the functions $\phi_s,\psi_s$ is $2/\pi$ and not $2\cdot\left(2/\pi\right)^3$? They should be normalized, or?

Comment: Well yes they should be normalised in that $\lim_{s\to 0}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)dx$ should be $1$. I think that's so with the prefactor of $2/\pi$ ... where did you get $2\cdot(2/\pi)^{3}$?

Comment: I calculated also the integral over $s$ from 0 to $\infty$. Why do they only need to be normalized for $s\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: That sounds good! Please share—I didn't manage to calculate any integral over $s$ myself. But no, I don't think there's any reason that integral should be "normalised". Basically the distribution starts with mass 1 at the origin, but then loses mass through escape at the boundaries as time passes.

Comment: Sounds reasonable; because of the Dirichlet and not Neumann boundaries, right?
Concerning the integral: The first one over $x$ is $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos((2n+1)x) \, {\rm d}x = \frac{2(-1)^n}{2n+1} \, .$$ Then the integral over $s$ is $$\int_0^\infty e^{-(2n+1)^2s} \, {\rm d}s = \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \, .$$ Finally you need to calculate $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{2^4} \, .$$

Comment: So heuristically; since for large times, the variance becomes large and therefore also the probability vanishes that the random walk is somewhere inside the domain $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Comment: That's broadly correct but in fact the mass will fall more quickly than it suggests because we assume that once the particle escapes the interval it's Game Over. Thanks for your integral and summation. It should lead to the expected (1-dimensional) survival time $\pi^{2}/4$. However thanks to your input I realised I had missed a factor of $1/2$ in the exponent. That's fixed now. What we really want is the integral of the squared term that appears in the main text of my answer, so let me know if you can evaluate that!

Comment: @Ali Thank you for your explanations and the discussion. As I already mentioned I am still familiarizing with PDE theory so I would not be able to spot any mistakes but however most of your answer and comments is clear. 
What is not clear to me: Let's say we consider the $L^\infty$ norm and assume that this integral of the squared term converges. What would the final upper bound for the initial integral look like? You separated two cases and if we put those together we have the $\epsilon$ in it, for which the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ does not exist, right?

Comment: @Ali: How do you arrive at \begin{equation*}
  \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\leq
  k_{p}
    \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)
\left\lVert u\right\rVert_{L^{p}} \, ?
\end{equation*}

Shouldn't it be $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \phi_s(x) u(x) \, {\rm d}x \leq ||\phi_s|| \, ||u||$$ for some $L^p$ norm? But $||\phi_s||$ is not necessarily $k_p \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(2n+1)^2/2 \, s}\, .$

Comment: I mean, if $||$ is the $L^2$-norm, then $$  \mathbb{E}\left[g\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}
  \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\right)
  \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\psi_{s}(y)v(y)dy\right) \, {\rm d}s \\ 
\leq \int_0^\infty {\rm d}s \, ||u|| \, ||v|| \, \frac{4}{\pi^2} \left( \sqrt{ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {\rm d} x \sum_{n,m=0}^\infty e^{ - (2n+1)^2/2 \, s - (2m+1)^2/2 \, s} \cos((2n+1)x)\cos((2m+1)x) } \right)^2 \\
=\int_0^\infty {\rm d}s \, ||u|| \, ||v|| \, \frac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{ - (2n+1)^2 \, s} \frac{\pi}{2}  \\
= ||u|| \, ||v|| \, \pi/4\, .$$

So no square.

Comment: Mimimi I added to my answer.
@Diger: Let $p,q$ satisfy $1/p+1/q=1$. Then with
\begin{equation*}
  k_{p}=\frac{2}{\pi} \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
  \left\lvert \cos\left((2n+1)x\right)\right\rvert^{q} dx\right)^{1/q}
\end{equation*}
(which will be independent of $n$), we have
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x)dx\leq
  \left\lVert \phi_{s} \right\rVert_{q}
  \left\lVert u \right\rVert_{p}
  \leq k_{p}
  \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}\right)
   \left\lVert u \right\rVert_{p}.
\end{equation*}
Note the second inequality is an inequality.

Comment: So, you pulled the norm also into each term of the infinite series? Isn't $$||\phi_s||_q  = \left( \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {\rm d}x \, |\phi_s(x)|^q \right)^{1/q}\,?$$ In this expression there will be a $q$-sum of the form $\sum_{n_1,...,n_q=0}^\infty$, where did that go? Or is $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} dx\,|\cos((2n_1+1)x) \cdots \cos((2n_q+1)x)| \leq \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} dx\,|\cos((2n+1)x)|^q \, ?$$

Btw, as my previous reply shows for the $L^2$-norm you don't have to do that and get a pretty simple looking bound: $E[g] \leq \frac{\pi}{4} \, ||u|| \, ||v||$. Not sure how good it is though.

Comment: @Diger Yes I pulled the norm into each term of the infinite series.
\begin{equation*}
  \left\lVert \phi_{s} \right\rVert_{L^{q}}
  \leq
  \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
  e^{-\frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^{2}s}
  \left\lVert \cos\left((2n+1)x\right) \right\rVert_{L^{q}}.
\end{equation*}
This is true by the subadditive property (triangle inequality) for norms.
There is no $q$-sum in there.
Thanks for your input! I have acknowledged the superiority of your approach in my answer. Why not write your own answer and win a hundred points? I have pretty much forgotten the question by now :)

Comment: Just curious: For the standard brownian motion, the increments are stationary and normally distributed. As your approach makes use of a solution of a PDE, I'm wondering if these solutions $\psi_s,\phi_s$ do actually obey these criteria, or am I missunderstanding something here?

Comment: Besides: I guess neither bound is better or worse. Consider the constant function $u=v=1$, then your bound gives $E(g)\leq 1.522$ while my bound below gives $E(g)\leq\pi^2/4 \approx 2.4674$; so it is worse in this case (actually the worst case). On the other hand, for any more localized function the $L^2$ norm is preferable. E.g. for $u=v=\left|\frac{2x}{\pi}\right|$ my bound gives $E(g) \leq 0.822467$.

Comment: @Ali Thank you for your answers, comments and edits. This helped me a lot! I appreciate your support. I think your 2nd edit which includes input from Diger summarizes the results good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I think that Ali had done the spadework to tackle the problem by his PDE approach, it might be worthwhile to post my own conclusion based on this. Since it was already mentioned in the above discussion that the $L^1$ norm is problematic, as it leads to divergencies (for $h\rightarrow 0$), I decided to continue using the $L^2$ norm. In this regard, if $||\cdot||$ is the $L^2$ norm, then the following sequence of steps sets a simple upper bound.
$$\mathbb{E}\left[g\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}   \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\phi_{s}(x)u(x) \, {\rm d}x\right)   \left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\psi_{s}(y)v(y) \, {\rm d}y\right) \, {\rm d}s \\
\leq ||u|| \, ||v|| \int_0^\infty ||\phi_s|| \, ||\psi_s|| \, {\rm d}s \\
= ||u|| \, ||v|| \int_0^\infty \left( \sqrt { \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |\phi_s(x)|^2 \, {\rm d}x } \right)^2 {\rm d}s \\
= ||u|| \, ||v|| \, \frac{4}{\pi^2} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}s { \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} {\rm d} x \sum_{n,m=0}^\infty e^{ - (2n+1)^2/2 \, s - (2m+1)^2/2 \, s} \cos((2n+1)x)\cos((2m+1)x) } \\ 
= ||u|| \, ||v|| \, \frac{4}{\pi^2} \int_0^\infty {\rm d}s \sum_{n,m=0}^\infty e^{ - (2n+1)^2/2 \, s - (2m+1)^2/2 \, s} \, \frac{\pi}{2} \, \delta_{n,m}  \\ 
= ||u|| \, ||v|| \, \frac{2}{\pi} \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}}_{\pi^2/8} \\
= \frac{\pi}{4} \, ||u|| \, ||v|| \, .$$

Here, as in Alis answer
$$\phi_s(x)=\psi_s(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(2n+1)^2/2 \, s} \, \cos((2n+1)x) \, .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! This helped me a lot!

Comment: You claim that $$\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2} \cos((2n+1)x)\cos((2m+1)x) dx= \frac{\pi}{2} \delta_{n.m},$$ right? For some reason I don't see why this is true. Why do terms with $n\neq m$ vanish?

Comment: It is pretty straight forward integration: $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(mx)\cos(nx) \, {\rm d}x = \frac{2m\sin(m\pi/2)\cos(n\pi/2)-2n\sin(n\pi/2)\cos(m\pi/2)}{m^2-n^2} \, .$$ Now if $m \neq n$ are both even/odd, then the sine/cosine is zero. $m=n$ is obviously greater zero.